# Best case of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If I have a recursive algorithm for a certain data structure for example

```
Algo(Tree T)
    if T == null
        return false
    ...
```

Will the best case of this algorithm be when the tree is null? The time complexity is O(1)?

Answer (score 3):

Usually when talking about best-case time complexity for an algorithm, we would say it's the best-case for an input of size `n`.

For example, consider a sorting algorithm.  If the sorting algorithm makes no changes and only iterates once if the input list is *already sorted*, then we'd say that in the best case, the algorithm is `O(n)`.  Of course, the input list could be empty, but that has no bearing on the way the number of operations grows as `n` increases.

Comment: So if I will look for a certain key in a tree with n nodes, thr best case is if the key is on the root?

Comment: Yes, if the algorithm terminates immediately thereafter, then that sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to consider work with structure of size `N > 0`

For empty data almost algorithms would have O(1) complexity (except for ones that prepare internal data before input checking)